# Bhairavas and Navagraha

Tags: shiva, avatars, astrology, navagraha, bhairava

Are these correspondences between Bhairavas and different Grahas correct?

Vatuka Bhairava - Mars

Mahakala Bhairava - Saturn

Kala Bhairava - Lagna (also like Mahavidya Bhairavi)

Asitanga Bhairava - Jupiter

Ruru Bhairava - Sun

Chanda Bhairava - Mars

Krodha Bhairava - Moon

Unmatta Bhairava - Saturn

Kapala Bhairava - Venus

Bhishana Bhairava - Rahu and Ketu

Samhara Bhairava - Mercury

It was possible to check the correspondences according to the traditional texts only for Vatuka Bhairava, he is the most popular of the *Bhairavs*, and Mars corresponds to him in Jyotisharnava Navanitam.
Also the correspondence of Mahakala Bhairava to Saturn is affirmed in Mahakala Shani Mrityunjaya Stotra.

Comment: Did you find these correspondences in some text? Similar correspondences exist for the Dashamahavidyas and Navagrahas as well as for Navadurgas and Navagrahas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have found confirmation of correspondence in the scriptures only for the first two. The remaining nine correspondences are taken by me from the Internet (for example, Wikipedia) and are the subject of this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Bhairavas are connected to grahas as follows:

Asitanga Bhairava - Guru

Ruru Bhairava - Shukra

Chanda Bhairava - Mangal

Krodha Bhairava - Shani

Unmatta Bhairava - Budha

Kapaala Bhairava - Chandra

Bheeshana Bhairava - Ketu

Samhaara Bhairava - Rahu

Swarnakarshana Bhairava - Surya

Vatuka ( Samskrit: Child) and Kaala Bhairava have no connection to any graha.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? You should add a source.

Answer (score 2):

In Varanasi, everyone identifies Kalabhairav with Rahu and Vatukabhairav with Ketu. Hanuman is identified with Shani.
This is a living tradition. The temples of these deities are visited incl. to correct the influence of these grahas.

**Both of these correspondence lists come from Tamil Nadu:**

• Asitanga Bhairava - Jupiter

• Ruru Bhairava - Sun

• Chanda Bhairava - Mars

• Krodha Bhairava - Moon

• Unmatta Bhairava - Saturn

• Kapala Bhairava - Venus

• Bhishana Bhairava - Rahu and Ketu

• Samhara Bhairava - Mercury

https://youtube.com/watch?v=QBf0KkXjhw0

https://youtube.com/watch?v=L_40C0KrL6M

https://youtube.com/watch?v=MAhn0kMAeQE

• Asitanga Bhairava - Jupiter

• Ruru Bhairava - Venus

• Chanda Bhairava - Mars

• Krodha Bhairava - Saturn

• Unmatta Bhairava - Mercury

• Kapala Bhairava - Moon

• Bhishana Bhairava - Ketu

• Samhara Bhairava - Rahu

• Svarnakarshana Bhairava - Sun

https://m.dinamalar.com/temple_detail.php?id=2698

https://santhipriya.com/2016/03/kshetrabalapuram-ananda-kala-bhairava-e.html

**Therefore, it is appropriate to use them only in Nadi-Jyotish.
In classical Jyotish, other correspondences must be used.**