# Kalabhairava and Shani (?)

Tags: astrology, shani, bhairava

Which **traditional text** states that Kalabhairava corresponds to Shani (Saturn)?

For example, the Shaktisangama Tantra states that Kalabhairava is the shaktiman of Dhumavati.
It is known that Dhumavati corresponds to Ketu, and not Shani at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello welcome to the site :) .. Following is very similar Q, it says Unmatta Bhairava is the ruler of Saturn -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/49625/4732

Answer (score 2):

Shaktiman (Kalabhairava) does not have to coincide astrologically with his Shakti (Dhumavati).
Shiva is the Sun and Parvati is the Moon. Vishnu is Mercury and Lakshmi is Venus...

In the Shiva Purana and Skanda Purana, the deity Kalabhairava is identified with the ancient Vedic deity Kala. There the name "Kala" is actually used as an epithet for Kalabhairava:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226404.html

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423769.html

In the Jaimini Samaveda, the messenger of the deity Kala is identified with Rahu:

https://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/sv/jaigs/jaigs.htm?jaigs002.htm#SV_JaiGS_2_9_a

Also in "The Upanayana: The Hindu Ceremonies of the Sacred Thread" the deity Kala himself is identified with Rahu:

https://books.google.com/books?id=WmsAjRBZXy8C&pg=PA96&dq=om+brahmane+namah&hl=com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLyfzHitD1AhWtQvEDHWgABUcQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF&f=false

And in Sringeri Pitham they say that Kalabhairava corresponds to Rahu:

https://sringeri.net/temples/the-guardian-deities/sri-kalabhairava

Therefore, do not believe those who claim that Kalabhairava corresponds to Saturn or Lagna. This is usually written by illiterate Indian astrologers, and other amateurs only repeat after them, and even Wikipedia managed to enter these nonsense.
Kalabhairava, quite obviously, corresponds to Rahu Graha.

Comment: Not written by illiterate astrologers. They are not that capable given that they are illiterate. Such correspondence are most probably found in Tantras. Even the corelations linking the Dasha Mahavidyas with the Navagrahas and the Lagna are found in Tantras.

Comment: Please give the necessary quotes from the Tantras. If such quotes really exist, then this will not be a problem for you.

Comment: I don't know any such quotes but that does not mean they don't exist. The no of Tantras is huge and moreover a lot among them have been lost. So it is sometimes very hard to find exact Tantric reference.

Comment: For example the relations between the Navagrahas and Dashamahvidyas have been mentioned in Tantras -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44490/4732

Comment: There is a link to the book by Sanjay Rath, and he quotes the text from an incomprehensible source. From which Tantra does he quote the sloka about Mahavidyas and Grahas?                                               In all published Shakta Tantras, the goddesses are identified not with the planets, but with the tithis of the Moon.

Comment: Well, let's say that we know exactly the correspondences of ten Mahavidyas to different planets and lagna. What does this give us, how can we determine the graha of Kalabhairava through these data? Kalabhairava is attached to Dhumavati, according to the Shaktisangama Tantra. Dhumavati is Ketu, not Saturn or Lagna. And I have already given examples that shaktiman and his shakti can have completely different correspondences to grahams.

Comment: We can't get the relation between Saturn and Kalabhairava from the correspondences between Dasha Mahavidyas and the Navagrahas. That's not what I'm saying too. But just like those correspondences exist similar correspondences might existing co relating Bhairvas and the Navgrahas. Since the Tantric scriptures are huge in numbers (and many lost) we can't be sure if some Tantras gave the required correspondences or not.

Comment: Those co relations between Dasha Mahavidyas and the Navagrahas are quite well known. And as I have said giving the exact necessary references from Tantras is not always possible.

Comment: It could be a lot easier Sir. 
1) Mahakala is identified with Saturn in the Martandabhairava Tantra. From this Tantra comes the famous hymn Mahakala Shani Mrityunjaya Stotra. 
2) Mahakala in the Skanda Purana 4.1.31.66-68 is identified with Kalabhairava. 
3) Considering other texts, such as the Mahakala Samhita, etc., we can conclude that these are two moods of one avatar of the god Shiva. When he is more thoughtful, he is called Mahakala, and when he is more active, he is called Kalabhairava.

Comment: So you are saying the consorts (Shaktis) of the respective Mahavidyas should be associated with the Grahas too?

Comment: And why not, if Shiva is associated with the Sun, and Mahakala with Saturn, according to the texts...

Answer (score 1):

The opinion that Kalabhairava corresponds to Saturn obviously comes from the so-called **Lal Kitab (Rādhākr̥ṣṇa Śrīmālī)**, pages: 128, 206 and 214. However, many contradictions of traditional Indian astrology are found in this book, since it has been corrupted by muslim-astrologers. In general, this book has a rather dubious origin.
More importantly, almost everywhere in the temples of northern and southern India, astrologers generally agree that Kalabhairava corresponds to Rahu. For more details see: **Words of Destiny: Practicing Astrology in North India (Caterina Guenzi)**.
Therefore, it is known that the specific time of Rahu-Kala is considered suitable for the worship of Kalabhairava.

Answer (score 0):

In Tamil Nadu, Kalabhairava is identified with Saturn. This is where this ancient tradition comes from. Details here:

https://m.dinamalar.com/temple_detail.php?id=2699

https://temple.dinamalar.com/Slogandetails.php?id=2062

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/36735)